# data.table filter on column1 %like% column2

Tags: r, data.table, grepl

I am currently attempting to filter a table, but am running into issues with `grep` vectorisation.

I have a `data.table` with two columns that I am wanting to use for filtering.

```
dt1 <- data.table(col1 = c("ab", "cd", "ef", "xy"),
                  col2 = c("ab123", "de987", "ef345", "ab123"))

#    col1  col2
# 1:   ab ab123
# 2:   cd de987
# 3:   ef ef345
# 4:   xy ab123
```

I am wanting to filter records based on when `col1` is `%like%` `col2`.

My problem is when I try:

```
dt1[col1 %like% col2]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: col1,col2
Warning message:
  In grepl(pattern, vector) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I get don't get the desired results, and I get the warning telling me that my pattern (`col1`) is >1.

The output I am hoping to get is:

```
# DESIRED OUTPUT
#    col1  col2
# 1:   ab ab123
# 2:   ef ef345
```

I suspect it needs some way to limit the input of col1 to being a single value for the row. I've tried a couple of things with `.I` but am still trying to figure out some of the less common cases with `data.table`.

Comment: You can force it to do a row-by-row operation with something like `dt1[ dt1[ , .(grepl(col1, col2)), by = col1 ]$V1 ]`, but, i'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you can use the vectorized `startsWith`:

```
dt1[startsWith(col2, col1)]
```

However, in the general case where you want a regular expression, you'll need to run through each row:

```
dt1[dt1[, grepl(.BY[[1L]], col2), by = "col1"][[2L]]]
```